# Obtain type of data member on C++03 at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, member, c++03

The following code tries to model a generic table with different types for the entries (where every entry contains key and value).
In the function "compareKeyWithEntry()", we need to use the type of the related key as a signature of a member function; to achieve that, decltype is used.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Key {
    int a;
};

bool operator ==(const Key &key_1, const Key &key_2) {
    return  ( key_1.a == key_2.a );
}

struct Value {
    int b;
};

struct Entry {
    Key key;  
    Value val;
};


template <typename Entry>
class Table 
{
public:

    Table(){}

    template <typename Key_T = decltype(Entry::key)>
    bool compareKeyWithEntry(const Entry& entry, const Key_T& key) {
        return operator==(entry.key, key);
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Entry e = { { 1, 2} };

    Table<Entry> table;
    std::cout << table.compareKeyWithEntry(e, e.key) << std::endl;
}
```

The current code is functional and achieves the objective.  But, is it possible to obtain the same result without 'decltype' ? (using C++03)

Comment: And why exactly do you need that `decltype`? Simply remove that template parameter's default.

Comment: removing the decltype would cause that the type Key_T can be anything; however I want to define a constraint: Key_t must be the type of the Entry 'key' member

Comment: Seriously, upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @Marda Unfortunately this is _not_ how you define such constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain a type of the member, but it is possible with SFINAE to achieve what you want just by asking if some type is the same as the type of the member.

```
typedef char yes_type;
struct no_type { char arr[2]; };

template <typename Key, typename Entry>
struct is_key_of
{
private:
    static yes_type test(Key Entry::*);
    static no_type  test(...);

public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test(&Entry::key)) == sizeof(yes_type);
};

template <bool> struct static_assertion;
template <>     struct static_assertion<true> {};
#define OWN_STATIC_ASSERT(x) ((void)static_assertion<(x)>())


struct Key {
    int a;
};

bool operator ==(const Key &key_1, const Key &key_2) {
    return  ( key_1.a == key_2.a );
}

struct Value {
    int b;
};

struct Entry {
    Key key;  
    Value val;
};


template <typename Entry>
class Table 
{
public:

    Table(){}

    template <typename Key_T>
    bool compareKeyWithEntry(const Entry& entry, const Key_T& key) {
        OWN_STATIC_ASSERT((is_key_of<Key_T, Entry>::value));
        return operator==(entry.key, key);
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Entry e = { { 1 }, { 2 } };

    Table<Entry> table;
    table.compareKeyWithEntry(e, e.key);
    //table.compareKeyWithEntry(e, 0); // static assertation raises
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/V_N9ME

You can replace static assertation with `enable_if` on return type if you want to remove the overload like in your question does `decltype`.